# How to make tighter an HTML fieldset?

Tags: html, css

Given a fieldset like this,
how can I reduce the gap between the paragraph and the surrounding line? I tried to tweak the margins like this:

```css
fieldset {
  margin: 1px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  border-top-right-radius: 1px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Personalia:</legend>
  <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
</fieldset>
```

However, it is not taking reducing the gap, what is the correct way of reducing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`p` tag has some default margin and `fieldset` have some padding, you'll need to remove those.

```css
fieldset {
  margin: 1px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  border-top-right-radius: 1px;
  padding:0;
  display:inline-block;
}
p{
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Personalia:</legend>
  <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, how do you reduce the gap at the right side next to the text?

Comment: The text inside the paragraph labels

Comment: you want to reduce the width of `fieldset`?

Comment: to reduce the width of the fieldset use: `fieldset {  display: inline-block; }`.

Comment: Yes it works, how do you know how all those parameters work? Just by reading the documentation or do you use some special tool?

Comment: Its just that I do not know all the parameters

Answer (score 4):

Margins are the space on the **outside** of elements.

To reduce the space between the edge of a fieldset and an element inside it you need to adjust the **padding** of the outer element and the margin of the **inner** element.

```css
fieldset {
  padding: 0;
}

fieldset p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Personalia:</legend>
  <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
</fieldset>
```